# Qt qml show device contact list

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml, contacts

I want to display device contact list on my app on Qt/QML(Android/iOS). Is there anyone to implement it in Qt/QML or should i do it on java(Android) and Objective-C(iOS)? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to call native code for stuff like that. No built-in solution in Qt.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my example on github, 
https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qmlcontactlist

```
package com.example.contacts.fetch; 
import android.provider.ContactsContract; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 

public class FetchClass extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity {
public FetchClass()
{
}
public static String getContacts(Context c) {
//ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},1);
String fetch="<root>";

Cursor phones = c.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    fetch+="<item><name>"+name+"</name><number>"+phoneNumber+"</number></item>";
}
fetch+="</root>";
return fetch;
} 
}
```